# How can I access the context in every function of a call chain with Kleisli?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, arrow-kt

I have a call chain of some methods, where I pass a context via a Kleisli. Basically I want to pass a context down to the db access layer, but I want to access this context everywhere in between.

The following example works perfectly. My problem though is, that I want to access the context in `OrderService.findAll(...)` as well. I tried several approaches but I keep failing.

```kotlin
object OrderRepository {
    fun findAll(userId: String): Kleisli<Context, ForIO, List<Order>> =
        Kleisli { ctx ->
            IO {
                ctx.db.query("someQuery")
            }
        }
}

object OrderService {
    fun findAll(userId: String): Kleisli<Context, ForIO, List<OrderResponse>> =
         OrderRepository.findAll(userId).map(IO.monad()) { orderList ->
            orderList.map {
                //Create OrderResponse from Order
            }
        }
}
```

Is it possible to access the context there, or doesn't this make any sense? Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need is a Kleisli from D to D, with D as the Context. That way you would have D (context) as the result type also, and you'd be able to flatMap and get access to it. That is why the method ask() provides, available over the companion.

Let's say your `OrderRepository` is also a dependency in the Context instead of a pure function (for the sake of the example), so you need to access it from within the context in the service. See:

```kotlin
interface OrderApi
interface OrderDB {
  fun query(query: String): List<Order> = TODO()
}

data class Order(val id: String)
data class OrderResponse(val order: Order)
data class Context(val api: OrderApi, val repository: OrderRepository, val db: OrderDB)

class OrderRepository {
  fun findAll(userId: String): Kleisli<Context, ForIO, List<Order>> =
    Kleisli { ctx ->
      IO {
        ctx.db.query("someQuery")
      }
    }
}

object OrderService {
  fun findAll(userId: String): Kleisli<Context, ForIO, List<OrderResponse>> {
    val monad = IO.monad()
    return Kleisli.ask<Context, ForIO>(monad).flatMap(monad) { ctx ->
      ctx.repository.findAll(userId).map(monad) { orderList ->
        orderList.map { OrderResponse(it) }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That said, Kleisli is a Monad transformer (also called ReaderT) that can be a bit convoluted to work with. If you want to inject dependencies on a functional codebase and stay simpler, my advice is to go for extension functions over a Context receiver, which already implicitly passes your dependencies across al levels, which is described [on this post by Paco](https://www.pacoworks.com/2018/02/25/simple-dependency-injection-in-kotlin-part-1/).

Comment: Wow, thanks for the helpful answer. That worked perfectly. Your articles are great btw, I learned a lot from them.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words :) I just edited the answer to add a probably better advice in the end.

Comment: Please note that `ReaderT` is a common pattern well known in the functional world, whereas _extension functions over a Context receiver_ is specific to Kotlin. I think one of the advantages of FP is the ability to share common patterns across languages.

Comment: @bob there is a higher order pattern in FP above the kinds of encodings like MTL and that is delimited continuations, the mother of all monads. That subsumes to imperative syntax the entire Functor hierarchy including monads like readers bringing application syntax to the environment through continuations. This what kotlin suspension is. Continuations is probably a better abstraction for JS and TS instead of the Haskell like encoding that ReaderT or any callback style encoding like the ones Scala and Haskell propose.

Comment: @RaúlRajaMartínez Delimited continuations are indeed very interesting. I didn't know that Kotlin utilizes this concept. I am aware that non-Haskell communities meet monads with skepticism. However, monads and their stacks are basically just about function application within an effectful context after all. I don't think this must be harder than composbale continuations. However, I'll take this in mind.

Answer (score 3):

@brewcode @bob there is a higher-order pattern in FP above the kinds of encodings like MTL and that is delimited continuations, the mother of all monads. That subsumes to imperative syntax the entire Functor hierarchy including monads like readers bringing application syntax to the environment through continuations. This is what kotlin suspension is.

@Jorge Castillo question is right but any lang with continuations support has better abstractions than wrapping in data types at allocation cost.

For JS and TS instead of the Haskell like encoding that ReaderT or any callback style encoding like the ones Scala and Haskell propose one based on delimited continuations if there is a way in those languages would be much cleaner and easier to use to beginners than wrapped callback style as ReaderT proposes. Look at the program below and see if this has any drawbacks over the wrapped version.

```kotlin
interface OrderApi

interface OrderDB {
  fun query(query: String): List<Order> = TODO()
}

data class Order(val id: String)

data class OrderResponse(val order: Order)

data class Context(
  val api: OrderApi,
  val repository: OrderRepository,
  val db: OrderDB) : OrderApi by api, OrderRepository by repository, OrderDB by db

interface OrderRepository {
  suspend fun Context.findAll(userId: String): List<Order> =
    query("someQuery")
}

object OrderService {
  suspend fun Context.findAll(userId: String): List<OrderResponse> =
    findAll(userId).map(::OrderResponse)
}
```